# CSS Disable background when div popup

Tags: css

This is what I am doing...

```
.parentDisable {
            z-index:999;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #aaa;
            opacity: .4;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
#board_dialog
{
           position:absolute;top:3%;left:30%;width:30%;height:210px;display:none;background-color:#ffffff;border:2px solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="board_dialog" title="Do Not Board Comment" class="parentDisable hide">
    <div class="popuphdr1">
        <div>  Do Not Board Comment</div>   
        <img class="popupclose" src="../lib/img/png/closebutton.png" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().hide()"/>   
    </div>
    <div> 
        <textarea id="board_textarea" class="popuptextarea"></textarea><br />
        <div class="popupfooter">
            <input onclick="toggleBoard();" type="button" id = "board_ok_btn" value="Ok" class="popupButton blue"/> 
            <input onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()" type="button" id = "board_cancel_btn" value="Cancel" class="popupButton blue"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results into showing "disabled pop up" and active background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()` is a terrible way to traverse the DOM, as any changes will almost guarantee breakage. Use like, `.parents('class')`

Comment: Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're looking for, but your main div (board_dialog) has style `display:none;` so you won't get anything whatever you do.

Comment: When I click a button, it shows popup disabled and background. window active. I want it other way round. Show disabled background.